# Como establecer un value default a getStringArrayList de un Bundle?

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un metodo que recibe en un `Bundle` los datos del cliente devueltos por el servidor, y este metodo se encarga de extraer los respectivos valores, en la cual, si por alguno caso no se encuentra un valor que devuelva un value default:

```
@Override
public void responseListener(boolean isCredencialesValidos, Bundle datosCliente) {
    if(isCredencialesValidos){
       String cliente_id = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_ID, null);
       String cliente_nombre = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_NOMBRE, null);
       String cliente_apellido = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_APELLIDO, null);
       String cliente_correo_electronico = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_CORREO_ELECTRONICO, null);
       String cliente_sexo = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_SEXO, null);
       String cliente_foto_perfil = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_FOTO_PERFIL, null);
       String cliente_token = datosCliente.getString(CLIENTE_TOKEN, null);
       ArrayList<String> cliente_roles = datosCliente.getStringArrayList(CLIENTE_ROLES, null);
    } else {
            //Usuario y/o password incorrecto(s).
    }
}
```

Pero en la linea de `ArrayList<String> cliente_roles = datosCliente.getStringArrayList(CLIENTE_ROLES, null)` no me deja establecer el valor por defecto `null`

Comment: y si pasas un array vacío en lugar de null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor predeterminado,  lo puedes establecer como un `ArrayList` vacío de valores tipo `String`:

```
new ArrayList<String>()
```

Esta sería la forma de realizarlo

```
 ArrayList<String> cliente_roles = datosCliente.getStringArrayList(CLIENTE_ROLES, new ArrayList<String>());
```